# Is it worth replacing MySQL with Parse.com while using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, parse-platform

Is it a good idea to use Parse.com instead of MySQL for a PHP based app? If yes, what are the upsides and downsides of going down this route? How do MySQL joins work if you are using parse?

Comment: I have not used Parse, but in a nutshell, their service seems to be *backend servers and application logic for people who do not want to worry about backend servers and application logic.* I.e. it's mainly for front-end mobile (iOS, Android etc) developers who have little backend skills or resources but need *some simple backend* for their mobile app. If you fit this description, it's probably a nice service. I wouldn't think about it as "replacing MySQL". Beyond that, this question is not really constructive.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The primary benefits of Parse are that you'll be able to work with application-level concepts like user accounts and push notifications rather than technology-focused concepts like databases and socket I/O. Using Parse helps share native models across server-side code and multiple clients. If you expect any amount of popularity, Parse's scale and Ops team will save you an immense amount of scaling pain.

Moving from PHP + MySQL to Parse may not be trivial, however, so Parse may not make sense for large projects already invested in these technologies. Parse doesn't provide a first-party PHP SDK, though there is an SDK listed in the third party section of the [API Libraries](https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries) list. The interface is also exposed natively with REST. Realistically speaking, however, this is because PHP is a server-side language and Parse aims to obviate the need for server-side coding. You might consider using their JavaScript library and seeing what is possible to implement client-side; if you really do need server-side execution (e.g. for high integrity + permission execution), the [Cloud Code](https://parse.com/products/cloud_code) environment also runs the JS SDK.

Your question regarding joins has a technical and philosophical component. Technically speaking, storing one Parse object in another is semantically equivalent to using a foreign key and queries have an "include" option which is functionally equivalent to a JOIN statement in SQL. A Parse Relation is an aggressively indexed join table suited for many-to-many relationships, though the tool doesn't allow includes across both sides of the join since it's intended to be used with high-arity collections. Philosophically, Parse is noSQL. This means your classes do not need to be as normalized as SQL tables typically are architected. Design your classes to encapsulate an idea and trust noSQL indexing to handle queries efficiently.

Comment: I think you should disclose here that you're a Parse.com developer.

Comment: Sorry, it's right on my profile that I'm an old timer Parse dev. Also, since originally answering this question we're released our first party PHP SDK which is our first open source project. Check it out at https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk

Comment: @ThomasBouldin What if we want to make use of existing database like MySQL with parse. I mean If there is already a website build using MySQL as backend and if we want an app as an extension for that website. Then obivously we will be using existing database. So how we can do that ?

Comment: If you are already hosting your own backend and managing your own database then it's not clear what want Parse to handle. Parse requires you to host your data in their cloud for you to use their API.

Comment: Parse.com has released its PHP SDK now.